# Is it better to update all records or reindex while using solr?

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj

I am using solr search engine. I had defined a schema initially and imported data from SQL db to solr using DIH. I have got a new column in sql db and value to which is getting populated using some of the previous columns. Now, I have to index this new column into solr.

My question is: do I perform update for all records or do I delete all records from solr and rebuild index again using DIH? I am asking this question because I have read that if we perform update for any document, solr first deletes the index and then rebuild it again.

Comment: Hi, the statement "if we perform update for any document, solr first deletes the index and then rebuild it again" is wrong and I would be really worried if Solr deleted the whole index just to update a document. It's true though that  document updates don't exist in Solr, but a document having the same unique id gets deleted and then the new document is indexed. So, indexing from scratch it's probably giving you some sort of advantage, however you won't be able to do that once your index will get big enough.

Answer (score 3):

The answer regarding speed is, as always, "it depends". But it's usually easier to just reindex. It doesn't require all fields to be stored in Solr and it's something you'll have to support anyway - so it doesn't require any additional code.

It also offers a bit more flexibility in regards to the index, since as you note, if you are going to do partial updates, the actual implementation is delete+add internally (since there might be fields that depend on the field you're changing, update processors, distribution across the cluster, etc.) - which requires all fields to be stored. This can have a huge impact on index size, which might not be necessary - especially if you have all the content in the DB for all other uses anyway.

So in regards to speed you're probably just going to have to try (document sizes, speed of DB, field sizes, etc. is going to affect that for each single case) - but usually the speed of a reindex isn't the most important part.

Answer (score 0):

If you update your index don't forget to optimize it afterwards (via the Admin console for example) to get rid of all the deleted documents.